# How can I make my phone stop displaying emoji?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, dolphin-browser, emoticons

At some point in the recent past, my phone (a Samsung Galaxy S4) started to display several large swaths of Unicode codepoints as emoji characters--including several that are used for other things, like U+2609, the astronomical symbol for the sun, which is now displayed as a little image of a sun.

How can I get rid of these? Everything I find on google is either about how to disable the emoji *keyboard*, or about how to *enable* emoji; what I want is a simple, device-wide system to get rid of emoji altogether and replace them with the symbols that the codepoints are meant to represent.

If there isn't any way to do this device-wide, is there at least a way to do it for the Dolphin browser?